# Entity Framework C# - Include doesn't not really Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight

I have an issue to include children to my objects.

On the server side :

```
    public List<Parent> GetParentsWithChildrenByCategoryId(int categoryId)
    {
        var parents = this.ObjectContext.Parents.Include("Children")
                          .Where(parent=> parent.CategoryId.Equals(categoryId))
                          .ToList();
        return parents ;
    }
```

But on the client side (silverlight app) I don't have the children attached to my parents.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Yeah. Use a debugger. It the children are there in the alarmes variable, you ask the totally wrong question. As in: EF has then loaded them and it is your communication layer that is not sending them to the client. That is totally so not EF's fault in this case...

Comment: I used a debugger, the children are linked to the parent on the server side but in the return of my query, there aren't. I also used the developper tools of Internet Explorer to see what data is sent and there is no children in the the parent.

Comment: So then the problem isn't with EF it's with your data transmission

Comment: Well, then I suggest you do not bother us with a useless question and information we do not want (the query) but start biving us the relevant issue - i.e. how you send the data to the client. Yoour whole question focuses on the server query side (not that you do provide a lot of code) and you jsut confirmed this part works. Now edit the question and start focusng on the stuff that does not - and that is not related to Entity Framework at all.

Comment: With WCF Data Services you must use `Expand` from the client.